# on the basis of a condition, can we add item and delete item to and from a combobox after it is bind to datasource

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

on the basis of a condition, can we add item and delete item to and from a combo box after it is bind to data source. is it possible to give items value to null in spite of 0.

if (!this.rowAttribute.cboFormat.Items.Contains("Column Attribute"))
                                this.rowAttribute.cboFormat.Items.Insert(0, "Column Attribute");

Answer (score 0):

This situation is handled by updating the source to which the ComboBox is bound.  If that DataSource utilizes the appropriate events (i.e. BindingList), the ComboBox will be automatically upated.

```
BindingList<string> myList = new BindingList<string> {"A", "B", "C"};

cboFormat.DataSource = myList;
```

-- ComboBox displays A, B, and C

```
myList.Add("D");
```

-- ComboBox displays A, B, C, and D